# How to estimate size of hole damaged in the tank?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, flow, bernoulli-equation

the vessel crew reported that they suspected bottom hull of the vessel is leaked as they found out a Void Tank have a sea water ingressed and now the tank full with Sea Water. Luckily the tank watertight integrity is good, and able to prevent water ingress into the machinery space.

Vessel will be heading for docking and emergency repair.

I would like to seek assistance to estimated the hole damage on the tank.

the data available:

1. Vessel draught, height from bottom hull to water surface, 4.2 Meter
2. Tank Capacity, 56.77 cubic meter.
3. Water flowrate (water ingress into tank), 3 m3/hr
4. Sea water temperature, 29 celsius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is an estimate and is not guarenteed to be accurate or correct, so you should check with experts in boat damage and repair.

From Bernoulli's principle at depth $h$ water  initially enters the hole at speed $$v=\sqrt{2gh}$$

If we assume the hole is at the bottom of the tank then $h=4.2$m. The average inflow rate is about $\frac{Av}{2}$ and from the $3$ cubic meters per hour or $0.000833$ cubic meters per second, we have

$$A\sqrt{2gh} = 2\times 0.000833$$

giving the area of the hole $$A = 1.84 \times 10^{-4} m^2$$

Or about $2 cm^2$.

Comment: Hi, John, would like to know reason for average inflow rare, Q = AV/2; why 2?

Comment: @Danial Area times velocity gives the flow rate in cubic meters per second, the divide by two is that the velocity would approach zero as the pressures equalise and only be the initial $v$ at the start.  The divide by 2 is an estimate, an exact working out might lead to a similar numerical factor e.g. 0.4 or 0.6 instead of 0.5, but other things are estimated anyway, so the divide by 2 seems ok for an estimate.